# Why do nearby cells have similar meiosis periods?

Tags: meiosis, experiment, cell-cycle

A few days ago, I conducted an experiment to observe the meiosis of rye ears. During the experiment, I observed that cells in similar locations have similar meiosis period. Can anybody tell me why does this happen? Does the checkpoint of a single cell affects the checkpoint of nearby cells?